# tutorials/books to create a plugin/module/library?

Tags: php, frameworks

i wonder if there are tutorials/books explaining how you create a library/plugin/module for other to implement?

libraries/frameworks like solr, doctrine, codeigniter etc.

cause it seems that they follow the same pattern. having one "bootstrap" file to load configurations, other classes and so on.

i aim to understand the basics, so i can create a such library.

cause at the moment i want to code an address book that other can use. just include a bootstrap file and they are ready to use my classes (like Doctrine).

recommendations of sources to learn these things of stuff?

you experienced guys, how did you learn it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends - if you're not creating anything visual (resp. anything missing presenters/controllers), it shouldn't be problematic. Just put it into `libs/components` etc. directories.

If you're creating for example universal administration where presenters/controllers are present, which is placed in proper module folder (every framework has this feature): I wouldn't worry about shipping it so. But you may consider packing it such as whole project.

If you're looking for basic MVC tutorials, check out http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html.